# CSS error: Image CSS set permanently to 'display:none ! important;

Tags: html, css, web

Well, basically i created a image inside a div using the img tag in a HTML file that i've been writing and the image just wont show up on the browser. Inspect says the image cannot be loaded and it's CSS is set to 'display: none!important'.I wasn't able to untick it even in inspect. Can you help me?

1. No class was declared on the img tag and the div holding it.
2. I haven't written the 'display:none!important' css anywhere on the page.
   3.There are other images in the same page which is displaying perfectly fine. I placed another image on the div which is holding my problem-image and even it is showing up. Renaming the image works too [Although i would like to know why].

The code used:

```
<div class="col-1"><img src="../Home-Page/images/twitter-logo-silhouette.png" alt="twitter"></div>
```

Any other image will work fine,The image is now kept renamed by finding it in finder, the error is gone now. But i still would like to know why it is so. If i rename it back. The error will appear once again.

Comment: <div class="col-1"><img src="../Home-Page/images/twitter-logo-silhouette.png" alt="twitter"></div> is the code.

Comment: Please share more details in order to receive better help. Follow Pauli_D's links above to create a working example. Based on what you said, it sounds like something you might be missing is still being declared and causing the trouble.

Comment: Can you please share the full html and css? Is there a link to a page or can you create a stack snippet?

Answer (score -1):

Your adblocker is blocking the image out, i guess.

If you try to rename your file and alt tag without naming twitter it will work, as you mentioned above